# Processing queue codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to develop a system with CodeIgniter that makes requests on an API as scheduled in the database. How do I make that line of background processing?

I did some searching and found names like Gearman and PHP-resque. Are the best choices or recommend me something else?

Comment: search for `cronjobs`

Comment: @RonakPatel Cronjobs would be useful only to schedule the tasks, but I need to create a processing queue, lest they be doing several processes requests simultaneously.

Comment: So, you want to run multiple process at same time?

Comment: @RonakPatel I thought of a process that swirls indefinitely to manage a processing queue. When a new activity is scheduled a task can be scheduled in cron for that hour is added to the task queue of the background process.

Comment: Have you considered having a permanent server for that?